# Download content for my program (Unity3D)

Tags: unity-game-engine

in my program, I have some category that there are a lots of images into them. 
so my program has a big size when compiles on Android.
I prefer to make categories downloadable to reduce my main program size.
how I can do this ?

Comment: In your program you have some category? Can you please be more specific with what you are trying to accomplish? maybe post some things you have tried so far, or post code snippets for us of your project so we can understand a little better.

Answer (score 0):

Use the WWW class to pull the images direct from a sever.  See:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

// Get the latest webcam shot from outside "Friday's" in Times Square
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public string url = "http://images.earthcam.com/ec_metros/ourcams/fridays.jpg";

    IEnumerator Start() {
         // Start a download of the given URL
        WWW www = new WWW(url);

        // Wait for download to complete
        yield return www;

        // assign texture
        Renderer renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        renderer.material.mainTexture = www.texture;
    }
}
```

Source:
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW-texture.html